# How to show this vector field is irrotational?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

I have the field:
$$\bar a(\bar r)=r \bar c + \frac{(\bar c\cdot \bar r)}{r}\bar r$$
where $$\bar c $$ is a constant vector.

I have worked through the problem and I cant seem to easily show that:
$$ \bar \nabla \times \bar a (\bar r ) = 0 $$

I get instead $$-(\hat r\times\bar c)$$.
Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: compute $\mathrm{div}(a(\bar r))$ and show it is not zero.